# ImportError: No module named site deploying Django with mod-wsgi and httpd

Tags: django, apache, deployment, mod-wsgi, centos7

I'm trying to deploy a django project on CentOS 7, but I keep getting `ImportError: No module named site` on my httpd error log.

This is my config file for httpd located at `/etc/httpd/conf.d`:

```
<VirtualHost *:8008>
        WSGIProcessGroup programa_registos
        WSGIDaemonProcess programa_registos python-home=/var/www/html/programa_registos/.env python-path=/var/www/html/programa_registos

        Alias /static /var/www/html/programa_registos/static
        <Directory /var/www/html/programa_registos/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/programa_registos/programa_registos/wsgi.py
        <Directory /var/www/html/programa_registos/programa_registos>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My project is located at `/var/www/html/programa_registos` and my virtualenv at `/var/www/html/programa_registos/.env`.

Here is my wsgi.py file, located at `/var/www/html/programa_registos/programa_registos`:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "programa_registos.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Your mod_wsgi is not compiled for the version of Python which your virtual environment is using. You can't mix versions. Variation of what is explained in the docs at http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#multiple-python-versions See also warnings about it in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: thank you! that helped!